# How can i get sum in java?

Tags: java, sum

I want to summation in java.

So,

> For example,
>
> > 1.123 + 1.123E-4 = 0.0123411234

So, How can i processing "E" in java?

Comment: That's [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Notation).  Your number is relatively small.

Comment: Your question is totally not about summation, which you clearly already know how to do.  It's about representing numbers in such a way that you can perform arithmetic on them.  The answer changes depending on the range of numbers you are working with and what precision you need, so you should provide that information.

Comment: Note that the equation you posted is incorrect.  The two numbers should sum to (approximately) 1.1231123.

Comment: @HotLicks that's an approximation?

Comment: @veer -- Floating point is always an approximation.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, but the way you originally stated that made it seem like you're confusing math with floating-point arithmetic (which has to do with computers trying to do math). The sum `1.123 + 1.123E-4` is `1.1231123` -- there is no approximation here. In Java, the sum of the floating-point literals `1.123` and `1.123E-4` may, however, be different due to imprecision, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
String a = "1.123";
String b = "1.123E-4";

double d1 = Double.valueOf(a);
double d2 = Double.valueOf(b);

System.out.println("sum = " + (d1 + d2));
```

Double's `valueOf()` method can parse te **E** notation for you.

And actually, the result is: 1.1231123

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = new BigDecimal( "1.123" );
    BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal( "1.123E-4" );
    BigDecimal sum = bigDecimal1.add( bigDecimal2 );
    System.out.println( sum );
}
```

Output:

```
1.1231123
```

Comment: Why BigDecimal necessarily? A double might be fine.

Comment: Not *necessary*, but it removes all precision problems

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BigDecimal` class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String) for a constructor that will take a string like "1.123E-4".

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you even try it?

```
final class SciNotationTest {

  public static void main(final String[] argv) {
    final double sum = 1.123 + 1.123E-4;
    System.out.println(sum);
    assert 1.1231123 == sum;
  }
}

C:\dev\scrap>javac SciNotationTest.java

C:\dev\scrap>java -ea SciNotationTest
1.1231123
```

You should be careful when using `double` and testing equality without tolerance, as floating-point can often be imprecise. If high-precision is what you're striving for, indeed use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parseDouble()` to do this...

```
String n1 = "1.123";
String n2 = "1.123E-4";

double dn1 = Double.parseDouble(n1);
double dn2 = Double.parseDouble(n2);


System.out.println("Total : " + (dn1 + dn2));
```

**Output:**

```
1.1231123
```